# Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массивов A и B, которые не являются общими для них

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Даны два массива: А[M] и B[N] (M и  N вводятся с клавиатуры). Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массивов A и B, которые не являются общими для них.

Можете объяснить как сделать это задание?

Comment: Минус за заголовок.

Comment: В таких условиях размер третьего массива *однозначно* определен входными данными. Ремарка про "минимально возможного размера" неуместна. Вам нужно вычислить симметрическую разность (XOR) двух множеств.

Comment: а не смотря на это , не знаете что надо сделать?

Comment: "Даны два массива"... Два массива **чего**?

Comment: два динамических массива с размерами М и N

Comment: Еще раз: Два массива **чего**? Что хранится в массивах????

Comment: @AnT, ну если массив - это указатель на выделенную память, а размер где-то сам по себе, то в заголовке имеется в виду, что надо выделить ровно столько элементов, сколько будет занято, а не резервировать больший размер. По крайней мере я так понимаю.

Answer (score 4):

Структура алгоритма - одна и та же для выполнения всех теоретико-множественных операций над упорядоченными последовательностями: пересечение, объединение, разность, симметрическая разность и т.п.

1. Отсортировать оба входных массива (напр. по возрастанию)
2. Синхронным проходом по обоим массивам получить результат.

Для вашего задания шаг 2 в стандартной библиотеке С++ уже реализован готовой функцией `std::set_symmetric_difference`.